# Getting bounced email. Error in the script

Tags: php, email, imap

I am trying to get bounced mail checking the body of the messages, but for some reason the script does nothing.

I checked all the documentation on the subject and searched for a solution but couldn't find anything.

I am sure some of you will be able to detect what I am doing wrong.

Here is the relevant part of the code.

```
error_reporting( E_ALL ) ;

$POP3Box = imap_open( "{" . $Domain . ":110/pop3/novalidate-cert", $EmailBox, $EmailPass ) ;

if ( !$POP3Box ) :
  echo '<br /><div class="ErrorMessage"> Connection failed!<br /> Wrong Email address or Password! Please check and try again...</div><br /><br />' ;
  die ;
endif ;

$MessageQty = imap_num_msg( $POP3Box ) ;
echo 'Total messages in "' . $EmailBox . '" = ' . $MessageQty . '<br /><br />' ;
$MailNum = 1 ;
$MailOrder = 1 ;

while ( $MailNum <= $MessageQty ) {// GET MESSAGES
  $EmailBody = imap_fetchbody( $POP3Box, $MailNum, 1 ) ;

  if ( strrpos( $EmailBody, 'Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender' )) {
    imap_delete( $POP3Box, $MailNum ) ;
    $MailOrder++;
  }
  else {
    die ;
  }
  $MailNum++;
}

if ( $MailOrder > 1 )
  imap_expunge( $POP3Box ) ;

if ( $MailNum > 1 ) {
  echo 'No bounced messages found!<br />' ;
}
else {
  echo 'Empty mailbox!<br />' ;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean `does nothing`? Try enabling errors display `ini_set( 'display_errors', TRUE );` to see what happens, maybe are not enabled in php.ini.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I did what you suggested, but still don't get any error. It's like the script is not executing and I am sure php is executing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found at least 3 issues in the script:

**This is an error:** `}` is missing after `...novalidate-cert"`

`$POP3Box = imap_open( "{" . $Domain . ":110/pop3/novalidate-cert", $EmailBox, $EmailPass );`

Must be changed to:

`$POP3Box = imap_open( "{" . $Domain . ":110/pop3/novalidate-cert"}, $EmailBox, $EmailPass );1`

**This is an error:** The closing command is missing. Add this after the `expunge`:

`imap_close( $POP3Box );`

**This a suggestion:** The string to search in the body can't be just `Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender`.

There are several messages that denote a bounced or returned email. I would suggest to replace this:

`if ( strrpos($EmailBody, 'Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender')) {`  with a regex like this one:

`if ( preg_match( "([a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)", $EmailBody, $BounceMatch )) {`

Detecting all bounced mail is almost impossible, but with the regex you will be able to catch close to 95%, which is really good.

In my opinion, the way you are doing it -checking the body of the message- is by far the more effective method.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Really appreciate your help. Now is working, I'll check for other issues.

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, you should check for errors in php code, I didn't.